# How to set default value for an array jschema object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, amazon-web-services, swagger

I'm trying to set default value for an array in jschema with swagger. Below is the example schema.

```
'Myobj': {
            'type': 'object',
            'title': 'Myobj',
            'description': 'Some text',
            'properties': {
                'outputForms': {
                    'type': 'array',
                    'description': 'Some text',
                    'default': 'two',
                    'items': {
                                'type': 'string',
                                'enum': ['one','two'],
                            },
                    'maxItems': 4,
                    'uniqueItems': true,
                    'additionalItems': false
                }
            }
        }
```

This does not work,what am I doing wrong ?
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: your default isn't an Array?

Comment: Do I need to use 'default': {items: 'two'} ?

Comment: I'd like to use 'two', and 'a default value for outputForms right' - yes

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
'default': 'two',
```

to

```
'default': ['two'],
```

The square brackets `[]` are used to denote an array.

Also, remove `additionalProperties`. In Swagger, the meaning of this key is different - it's an object (not a boolean) and is used to define a [map / dictionary](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#model-with-mapdictionary-properties).

Comment: I'm not shere how, but it gets the first element in array, e.g. if I set 'two' as first element in array it will be default value for outputForms

Comment: @nightmare: This is valid Swagger and works fine in Swagger UI (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjWHs.png). If your tool can't handle this, it must be a bug in the tool.

Comment: what should I do in order to see [ 'one', 'two' ] as default value?

Comment: @nightmare: `'default': ['one', 'two']`

Comment: the default is still 'one' http://prnt.sc/dedgnv, bun I need somehow to have  ['one', 'two']